# How collect failed address in Exim?

Tags: exim

How save to file email if you can not deliver the message?
Or the only way is to log analysis?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can check that with the command line. Here are the some useful link for you.

http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_exim_command_line.html

http://bradthemad.org/tech/notes/exim_cheatsheet.php